# AWS Sagemaker: Jupyter Notebook kernel keeps dying

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I get disconnect every now and then when running a piece of code in Jupyter Notebooks on Sagemaker. I usually just restart my notebook and run all the cells again. However, I want to know if there is a way to reconnect to my instance without having to lose my progress. At the minute, it shows that there is "No Kernel" at the bottom bar, but my file seems active in the kernel sessions tab. Can I recover my notebook's variables and contents? Also, is there a way to prevent future kernel disconnections?

Note that I reverted back to tornado = 5.1.1, which seems to decrease the number of disconnections, but it still happens every now and then.

Comment: From the description, it looks like you use the notebook to train a model, is that correct?

Comment: Actually it was happening when pre-processing a dataset prior to training.

Comment: it's recommended to run a separate data processing job if the data size is big. You can connect to an EMR cluster and run spark job on the EMR cluster and the output stored on S3.

Answer (score 1):

Often, disconnections will be caused by inactivity because a job is running for a long time with no user input. If it's pre-processing that's taking a long time, you could increase the instance size of the processing job so that it executes faster, or increase the instance count. If you're using EMR, you can now run an EMR Spark query directly on the EMR cluster since December 2021:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/12/amazon-sagemaker-studio-data-notebook-integration-emr/

There's a useful blog here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-backed-by-spark-in-amazon-emr/ which is helpful in getting you up and running.

Please let me know if you need more information, or vote for the answer if it's useful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me a quick solution was to open a Terminal instead, save the notebook file as a Pytohn file, and run it from the terminal within Sagemaker.